# How to get the user profile details of signed in user when 'Get access without a user' method used in microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, api, graph

I have used  'Get access without a user' method to use Microsoft graph API in my windows application. I need to retrieve the details of user who signed in and provided the admin consent. If I use 'me' request then the below error appears

> /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of permission in Microsoft Graph API - [Delegated and Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#delegated-and-application-permissions).

```
/me can not be accessed via an application authentication flow because there is no signed-in user.
```

A delegated authentication flow will look like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider).